# Remote RPC call is triggered again after one hour

Tags: gwt

I make a client call to the server and waiting for the response.There are a lot of DB operations done on the server part which makes the client to wait for more than a hour.
After 2 hours "StatusCodeException 0" is logged in UI logger but still the process on server side is continuing.
On examining the server logs i found that the RPC which is started initially is triggered again exactly after one hour with a different thread.

I found similar kind of a question which is not answered
[Remote Service in gwt is executed twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12688177/remote-service-in-gwt-is-executed-twice)

Help is appreciated

Thanks 
Aruna

Comment: Is the same issue you are facing ?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18820812/browser-it-self-making-request-on-request-failure-when-internet-reconnected

Comment: No 
In my scenario there is no network disconnectivity.The RPC call is triggerd again after 1 hr on its own.Is there any setting in GWT which triggers the RPC call again if the response from server is not recieved in one hour and throw a statuscodeexception 0 after 2 hours.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce that issue?? everytime exactly after one hour ?

Comment: yes the rpc call triggers again after one hour

Comment: No,No .There is no such setting.This is really weird. And mostly depends on browser also.May I know for which browser this happening? In my case IE is the culprit.BTW are you catching the exceptions in onFailure ?? That gives you more clues.

Comment: I am testing in chrome.I have not verified in IE and firefox. Yes in the onfailure i get StatusCodeException 0 after 2 hours in UI, but still the backend process continues to run.I tried even with increasing session timeout in web.xml to 3 hrs but still it fails after 2 hours.